# JAXB Marshalling an Object truncates the result string if too many items in object

Tags: jaxb, marshalling, truncated

I currently have this:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(javaObject.getClass());
        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(javaObject, stringWriter);
        String xml = stringWriter.toString();
```

The object contains a list of data_objects. As long as that list of data_objects is under 17 items I get a complete xml response. Once I have more than that the xml gets truncated. It does not throw an error. The xml string just has '...' at the end

```
<DataDetailObject xmlns:xsi="...
```

If I use System.Out instead of stringWriter I see the entire xml transformation correctly. What am I missing? Should I be using a different output for the marshalling?

Comment: Where do you see the value with `...` at the end?  Are you inspecting the `String` in a debugger or writing it to System.out?

Comment: It did not occur to me to inpsect the String thru System.Out. After I did I found it was working properly. What I found then was a misbehaving security module. There was no issue with the marshal. Thank you for your time

Comment: I have migrated my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `...` may be the behaviour of the debugger or viewer that you are using to introspect the `String`.  If you write it to `System.out` you should see everything working correctly.